# Getting the mouse coordinates when ButtonPressEvent occurs

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I've wrapped a drawing area in an event box so that I can catch mouse clicks with this function:

```
protected virtual void OnEventbox1ButtonPressEvent (object o, Gtk.ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Clicked!");
}
```

How can I find out *where* the mouse clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually that information is stored in the `args` object.  I'm not terribly familiar with Gtk, but I imagine it's not too dissimilar to the .Net click event implementation.

Comment: You seem to be right... I found four properties that help do the trick: `Console.WriteLine("Location relative to the current widget (" + args.Event.X + ", " + args.Event.Y + ")");` and `Console.WriteLine("Location relative to the computer screen (" + args.Event.XRoot + ", " + args.Event.YRoot + ")");`